# Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null (minecraft modding eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I've been trying to make a minecraft mod in eclipse but whenever I start it the minecraft window it flashes open and then closes and I get a crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

Time: 6/2/20 9:43 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:217)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.SplashProgress.createResourcePack(SplashProgress.java:731)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.SplashProgress.<clinit>(SplashProgress.java:99)
    ... 4 more
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:217)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_251, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 197682624 bytes (188 MB) / 253755392 bytes (242 MB) up to 3782737920 bytes (3607 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    Launched Version: 1.12.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics GL version 4.6.13587 Compatibility Profile Context 20.4.2 26.20.15029.27017, ATI Technologies Inc.
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
```

I've tried everything I can find on how to fix this (drivers are up to date, I have java 8, minecraft 1.12.2).
Normal minecraft works completely fine and my modpacks using twitch launcher work fine, it's only in eclipse that minecraft doesn't start.

Comment: Minecraft has historically been a bit tricky to start from an IDE, there's differing startup args per version and across different systems. If you're wanting to test changes in-game, it'd likely be better to have your IDE build your mod and automatically export it to your mod folder so you can simply start the game on your own.

Comment: @Sqepia This is about minecraft modding / programming, not playing the game. It's not a superuser question really, the only better place on the internet for it is somewhere like Forge forums.

Comment: @Sqepia Questions about problems with development tools (which is what this is) are on topic here.